# Interviewing with a company that "flaked" on me before. How to negotiate job security when interviewing for a new position with them?

Tags: interviewing, canada, tech-industry, job-security

A few months ago I was interviewing with Tech Company for a consulting job. The job was attractive for a few reasons, the main ones being a big pay increase, full-time, fully remote, good career move, and skill-wise it was a great fit. I also work in a relatively niche tech area so I don't see jobs like this that often. I was happy to make the jump.

However, in the very last round of interviews Tech Company pulled the job offer, saying the Client Company canceled the job on their end, so Tech Company had no more need to hire anyone. Worryingly, this was during a couple rounds of salary negotiations, meaning I could have potentially signed the contract *before* Client Company canceled the job - and after I might have already given notice at my current job! I'm not that experienced with the job offer process, but pulling the offer at the last second like this gave me a bad feeling and made me wonder how they work internally.

That said... it's been a couple months, and Tech Company has now gotten back in contact with me and are asking me to interview for a similar position. The position looks just as attractive for all the same reasons I posted above. However, I'm worried what would happen if I'm a month into the job and, again, Client Company removes the position (or something similar). Basically I'm worried about job security given what happened last time.

I'm looking for advice for how to approach job security while interviewing for this new job. Can I ask them to remove the probationary period (6 months)? Are there other things I can negotiate so I have peace of mind?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I'm looking for advice for how to approach job security while
> interviewing for this new job. Can I ask them to remove the
> probationary period (6 months)? Are there other things I can negotiate
> so I have peace of mind?

It might be hard for them to avoid the probationary period.

Ask them to explain what would have happened if you had signed the earlier offer. or if you had started work before the customer changed their mind.

Ask if the position has been funded by the customer. In my experience before the customer funds the position the offer usually has a contingency. This is to allow the customer the final approval. It also means you don't give notice until that contingency is removed.

Ask about what they do if the customer cancels. Someplace terminate quickly, others will give you weeks, or months to find another project.

If you don't like their answers, look elsewhere.

Answer (score 7):

> I'm looking for advice for how to approach job security while
> interviewing for this new job.

"Job security" and "new consultant" don't usually go together. If a client company cancels a project, that often means either reassignment or cutting those who were to be assigned to that client. That's just the way it works, depending on your contract.

Once you are with the company for a while, and assuming there are many active projects, your possibility of reassignment might increase. But there will seldom be real job security.

For this particular assignment, ask about the client. Mention what happened last time and gauge their reaction to see if they feel strongly that it won't happen again this time.

> Can I ask them to remove the probationary period (6 months)?

You can always ask. That may not increase your job security though. Read the contract carefully. See if it mentions what happens in the event of a client cancellation.

> Are there other things I can negotiate so I have peace of mind?

Everything is potentially negotiable. Decide what would give you peace of mind (perhaps a long notice period? perhaps specific severance pay?) and ask for it. Be prepared if the answer is "No".

Answer (score 5):

You *can* negotiate anything you want.  The question is, how will the other party feel about that.  You *can* say, "I don't want any probationary period", they *can* say "well that's too bad then, no job for you".

As for how to deal with this case in particular, simply tell them how you feel: "I have been in interview process with your company before, and you pulled the job last minute.  In order to take your job, I have to quit my current one, where I have job security and I know it won't be cancelled.  How will you guarantee my job security given that you've already canceled a position on me once before?".  This can go one of 3 ways, as far as I see it:

1. They can give you a satisfactory answer: "We promise we will pay you 6 months of salary, regardless of what happens, even if the job is pulled and we are unable to find a suitable replacement".
2. They can give you an unsatisfactory answer: "Things happen in the market and it is a volatile time for our clients, we can't guarantee your job security".
3. They can overreact: "You want a guarantee, huh?  We don't give guarantees, screw you".

In the first case, you got what you wanted.  They will give you some sort of guarantee of your salary and you don't have to worry about it.

In the second case, you have your information and you can make an informed decision.  You know it's a risk and you can decide for yourself whether or not to take it.

In the third case, you know this company is a bunch of assholes (or possibly worse, scammers) and you can consider your bridge with them to be burnt and never talk to them again (and possibly also write a review of them on Glassdoor).